# NPM install something from github within a docker container fails

Tags: node.js, git, docker, npm

I have been trying to install something from a github repository and run it inside. I used `npm install github:openfn/core#v1.0.0` in my project directory which added `"core": "github:openfn/core#v1.0.0"` to the package.json. However when I try to build the docker container with `docker build -t name .` I get the following warnings and eventually error :

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/pino-pretty-fddda985/.travis.yml'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@babel/core-96a25426/lib/config/files/types.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@babel/core-96a25426/lib/config/util.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@babel/core-96a25426/lib/config/files/utils.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-node-d3ce1706/lib/rules/no-unsupported-features/node-builtins.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/filter.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-node-d3ce1706/lib/rules/prefer-global/process.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-node-d3ce1706/lib/configs/recommended-module.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-node-d3ce1706/lib/configs/recommended-script.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-node-d3ce1706/lib/configs/recommended.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/ajv-2fba4683/dist/ajv.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-node-d3ce1706/lib/util/strip-import-path-params.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-node-d3ce1706/lib/rules/prefer-global/text-decoder.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-node-d3ce1706/lib/rules/prefer-global/text-encoder.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-node-d3ce1706/lib/rules/prefer-global/url-search-params.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-node-d3ce1706/lib/rules/prefer-global/url.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-node-d3ce1706/lib/util/visit-import.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-node-d3ce1706/lib/util/visit-require.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/getIterator.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/Heap.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/initialParams.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/prettier-21fddb45/doc.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/isArrayLike.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/iterator.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/map.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/once.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/onlyOnce.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/parallel.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/promiseCallback.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/queue.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/range.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/reject.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/setImmediate.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/withoutIndex.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/internal/wrapAsync.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/async-67304d10/dist/async.mjs'
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/openfn/core.git
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

From other posts here, I have seen that the undefined ls-remote... and spawn git probably has something to do with not having git installed, however I think that would make sense if I was not using docker, but even so I do have git installed and can run git clone, git --version and so on. It is because of this dependency, as soon as I remove it, I am able to build it and run it without issues. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:dubnium-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD npm start 

EXPOSE 4321
```

Comment: What's the Dockerfile?

Comment: I have edited my question with the Dockerfile

Comment: I am not entirely understanding the method.
You want to build an app and then run it?
I'd rather pre-build the application and COPY the binary.
That way the image and container is much more minimal, NPM does not need to download and store the node-modules folder, among other things.

Comment: You say you have `git` installed; I don't actually see that in your Dockerfile.

Comment: @VikingPingvin thank you for your suggestion. I was following a tutorial from OpenHIM, that is why I did it this way.  Nevertheless I am very new to docker, I am not sure I know how to implement your suggestion.

Comment: @DavidMaze That is my part of my question, I have it installed outside of docker, I do not know how to install it in docker so that installing the dependency is possible.

Comment: @chaBing add a RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git.

Regarding my suggestion, I assume you have the source code on your local machine.
Use the npm install and build process, or use the node package 'pkg' to create executable binary files that contain all of your program.

Then you copy that executable to the docker image:
COPY <path-to-executable> .

And then tell docker to run the program upon start, instead of npm start

CMD ["./<path-to-executable> "]

Comment: I am sorry if what I am asking is stupid, but RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git gives me apt-get not found. My OS is macOS Mojave in case this information is necessary. I think I understand your suggestion now, and I will certainly give it a try later as it seems cleaner. With your last statement, do I understand it right that I should replace CMD npm start with CMD ["./<path-to-executable> "] ?

Comment: You need to run the apt-get command on the docker container. It is done via RUN directives in the dockerfile. Apt is the package manager for many Linux distributions, like Ubuntu, and I think Alpine as well, which you are using (see top of your dockerfile).

As per the CMD directive, yes, everything in a CMD directive is executed as a command when to container start. Your npm start command would have been executed on cotnainer start. But instead, if you have a binary runnable, you can directly run it instead. No need for npm.

Comment: @Yes i had, but apparently with Alpine I have to use: apk update and apk add which I now found out. However even after adding RUN apk update and apk add git I still get the same error as provided in the post. Thank you for the explanation on the second suggestion, I will try that one later and let you know.

Comment: It does not seem to work somehow, I get an error where I try to import the package that I am trying to install from github. Somehow it tries to find it, in the current directory where the file, importing said package, is located

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I managed to have it working by adding:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache git
```

to the dockerfile. Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: also working in case of permission issues on `non alpine` docker images